# Free Shipping adds a cost if product quantity is 2 or more

Tags: shipping

I have free shipping set for orders over $79, but if I make any 1 product a quantity of 2 or more it adds a small shipping cost. I can't figure out why. I have the free shipping set through Shopping Cart Price Rules to restrict shipping to Alaska and Hawaii, so all other free shipping methods are turned off. My only shipping carrier is UPS. I am using Magento version 1.9.2.4